# Issue with first implementation of NgRx Store

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, store

This is my first attempt to implement store from the scratch.
At this moment i have effect, reducer, action, index and registred everything in app module. Currently i want to subscripe to my store.
I tried to do it with [this](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/building-an-online-store-using-ngrx-store-and-angular?kw=&cpn=13466528117&&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=kendo-ui-angular-trial-search-bms-EMEA&ad_group=Angular%20DSA&utm_term=DYNAMIC%20SEARCH%20ADS&ad_copy=&ad_type=search_DSA&ad_size=DSA2_blazor-dsa_D1-complete-native-angular-ui-component-library-built-for-quality-and-performance&ad_placement=&gclid=CjwKCAiA4KaRBhBdEiwAZi1zzpfd0UJIwpb_SOaiKUEzukWIOVK6KAsOYbqSDFsUjUxFvdoeJL6KaRoC654QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) tutorial.
Currently i have error in line: `store.pipe(select('user')).subscribe(data => (this.players = data.players));`

This is a part of main-page.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Player } from '../../model/Player';
import { select, Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { GetPlayersAction } from 'src/app/store/user/actions';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-page',
  templateUrl: './main-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main-page.component.scss']
})
export class MainPageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private store: Store<{ players: Player[]}>
    ) { 
      store.pipe(select('user')).subscribe(data => (this.players = data.players));
    }

  players: Player[] = [];

  currentPlayer: Player;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store.dispatch(new GetPlayersAction());
  }
  


  logout() {
    this.authService.logout();
  }

  showUserProfile() {
    // TODO get logged in user and pass to profile view
    const currentUser: Player = {
      isCurrentUser: true
    }
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/', {skipLocationChange: true}).then(()=> this.router.navigate(['/profile', currentUser],{skipLocationChange: true}));
  }

}
```

Currently i have error like this:

> Error: src/app/components/main-page/main-page.component.ts:22:25 -
> error TS2769: No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 9,
> '(mapFn: (state: { players: Player[]; }) => unknown): (source$:
> Observable<{ players: Player[]; }>) => Observable', gave the
> following error.
> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '(state: { players: Player[]; }) => unknown'.   Overload 2 of 9,
> '(key: "players"): (source$: Observable<{ players: Player[]; }>) =>
> Observable<Player[]>', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '"user"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"players"'.
>
> Error: src/app/components/main-page/main-page.component.ts:22:73 -
> error TS2339: Property 'players' does not exist on type 'unknown'.

Comment: Seems you have typification problem. You're receiving data without proper type in select function. And because of that `players` can't be picked from `unknown` type.

Comment: Example tutorial is not good by my opinion. Any way you can omit typing, by `data => (this.players = (data as any).players)`. But you should not do that.

Comment: Ok, it fixed second error, but still have first one on 'user'

Comment: You shouldn't be using store.pipe with select. You should be using store.select and calling the selectors you have created.

Comment: Every code initialization should be handled in `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook, not in the `constructor`, second, you need to call it as `this.store`, not `store`. Also, try adding the action code for your `GetPlayersAction`